# Swift - not able to compile with instance checking

Tags: swift

I want to inspect if an object is an Optional String type at runtime. 
Why will the following not compile in my command line project?

```
var p:String?

if p is String {
    println("p is string")
}
else {
    println("p is not string")
}
```

Build Error:

```
Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
  %81 = bitcast i8* %80 to %SS, !dbg !131
Invalid operand types for ICmp instruction
  %82 = icmp ne %SS %81, null, !dbg !131
PHI nodes must have at least one entry.  If the block is dead, the PHI should be removed!
  %85 = phi i64 
PHI node operands are not the same type as the result!
  %84 = phi i8* [ %81, %73 ]
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: You're missing information here, like what specific error is reported, is it from a program, or a playground?

Comment: It's from a command line project.

Answer (score 3):

You first have to assign a value to it. Like this:

```
var p : Any?

p = "String"

if p is String {
    println("p is a String")
} else {
    println("p is something else")
}
```

Comment: You sure this is not a bug. You should be able to do  var p : String? = "String". Which when I do I get an error on the if p is String..

Comment: You don't have to assign a value, because it's an optional.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, XCode shouldn't be crashing on your code even if it incorrect, so I'd submit a bug report to Apple.

Your code doesn't really make sense though. You set p as an Optional String then ask if it is a String. An optional String can contain either a String or nil so you'd be better off just checking if it is not nil:

```
var p: String?

if p {
println("p is string")
}
else {
println("p is not string")
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Well what are you trying to accomplish with this piece of code?

Comment: To see if I can inspect the type of an object like I can with ObjC.  In this case, I want to inspect if an object is an Optional String type at runtime.

Comment: then shouldn't you use `if p is String?` then?